# Pointwise convergence imply uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

I am trying to find a condition under which a sequence of continuous functions on a metric space (or more generally in a topological space) which point wise converge to some function f should imply uniform convergence. Basically I am searching for a theorem which proves uniform convergence provided that we know pointwise convergence is true. Is there any such theorem? Thanks.

Comment: A nice such result is [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem): If the sequence is monotone and the domain is compact, then (pointwise) convergence implies uniform convergence.

Comment: If I remember correctly, pointwise convergence + equicontinuity gives uniform convergence. Although this might only be in $C(X)$, where $X$ is a compact metric space and $C(\cdot)$ is the space of continuous functions.

Comment: @kunalan : Thanks a lot.